# Cannot get GoogleMap object

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Strangely map=frag.getMap(); does not throw nullpointerexception , but still the map is always null!

The same situation with or without running the handler.

I see the map (world map) but cannot do anything with the map object.

PRINT SCREE with project properties : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGB65.jpg

Please have a look at the code and please advice where I am wrong.

```
package com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;


import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;




 public class Settings extends FragmentActivity{
    LinearLayout submenu;

     GoogleMap map;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

         submenu =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.submenu);
         SubMenu sm = new SubMenu(this,submenu);
         sm.getButtons();


       mainLayout  =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.temp);



      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

         @Override
         public void run() {


       MapFragment frag = MapFragment.newInstance(); 
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.add(mainLayout.getId(), frag);

      fragmentTransaction.commit();  

     map=frag.getMap();
      System.out.println("THEMAAP "+map);

      if(map != null) {
          System.out.println("THEMAAP NOT NULL "+map);
      }else{handler.postDelayed(this, 500);}

         }
      }, 500);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return ActionBar.HandleMenu(this, item.getItemId());

    }


}
```

and the is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.suntrainer.suntrainer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.suntrainer.suntrainer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>



    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppActionBarTheme" >


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDJuwvAd8Zzqasdasdadasdasd" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals.Locations"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCATIONS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals.Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals.WatchList"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.WATCHLIST" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bestsiteeditor.bestwirelessdeals.Profile"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply waiting 500 ms after the fragment transaction solved the issue.

Instead of Thread ,handler could be also implemented also.

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();  

Thread thread=  new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){ try { synchronized(this){wait(500);}}catch(InterruptedException ex){ }

        map=frag.getMap();
        System.out.println("MAP OK"+frag.getMap());

    }
};

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
android:minSdkVersion="12"
```

So you need to change

```
public class Settings extends FragmentActivity{
```

to

```
 public class Settings extends Activity{
```

Also it is better you check the availability of google play services before initializing 
google map object.

From the docs

> public final GoogleMap getMap ()
>
> Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this
>   fragment.
>
> Returns the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet
>   ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also
>   happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play
>   services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone
>   through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this
>   method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

Edit:

Missing a meta tag in the applciation tag of manifest fie.

Pls make sure you followed all the steps @

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: @BestSiteEditor check the availability of google play services before initializing the map object

Comment: I see the green sign next to google play service , is there a way to make test. the same library works fine in another my project

Comment: @BestSiteEditor check the edit and read Check for google play services @ http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: you should add google play services library to your project.You will find google play services lib in your sdk.

Comment: Did this: developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html  in my oncreate it returns : "Google Play services is available.");

Comment: @BestSiteEditor if its available and you have referenced the library project i see no reason why it won't work

Comment: @BestSiteEditor update your post by putting a edit section with the updated code if you followed the suggestion in my post

Comment: @BestSiteEditor you still don't extend Activity and you are missing a meta tag in your manifest and make sure you follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: I added the code - made the test and removed it. Why should I keep it in the code after I saw that the google play is working. What meta tag am missing in the manifest?

Comment: @BestSiteEditor what? i don't understand. What should you not keep?. Coz not all devices may or may not have google play services and it is better you check before using the map object. And see the docs for what meta tag you are missing.

Comment: and if you know the missing meta tag, why not tell it right away but you send me to check the docs. Do you think I have am not checking the docs last two days :)

Comment: @BestSiteEditor i did if you look at my post carefully and you have not followed my suggestion. I think you are not looking at my post properly

Comment: the version meta tag is for the latest version of google play service - from last autumn. I use older version and it is working perfectly on my other projects . without that tag

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46723/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-bestsiteeditor)

Comment: we are so far away - nothing will come out of it even if we make an awesome chat.

Comment: @BestSiteEditor then i won't waste time on this any more. good luck.

Comment: @BestSiteEditor you need to update google play services. and as of rev 13 you need the meta tag as suggested. If you don't want to follow the suggestion no problem. But its recommened. Well i tried my best to help solve you are problem but you insist on sticking to older version